# Determining the eigenspace of the matricial representation of a linear transformation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a very generic question about determining eigenspaces because I'm a bit confused...

Determining the eigenvalues of a linear transformation is the same as determining the eigenvalues of a matricial representation of that linear transformation, right?. Ok but then if we proceed to calculate the eigenspace of each eigenvalue we will get to 1 or more vectors for each eigenvalues. My main question is:

- Are the eigenvectors that I calculate vectors of coordinates of my linear transformation? And because of that I need to multiply each component of the vector by the correspondent component of the basis of the transformation?

I don't know if I'm being clear... 
Thanks!

EDIT:

Example to illustrate what I'm asking:

> Calculate the eigenvectors of the transformation $T: \mathbb{R^3}_{[t]} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}_{[t]} $ defined by $T= D$ (D is the derivative.

First thing i did was to consider a matricial representation of my linear transformation considering the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R^3}_{[t]} $

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0          \\[0.3em]
      0 & 0 & 2 & 0  \\[0.3em]
      0 & 0 & 0 & 3  \\[0.3em]
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}$

I proceed to calculate the characteristic polynomial and I get to $t^4$ which means having a single eigenvalue $0$.

The I calculated the eigenspace associated which is the {$x \in \mathbb{R} | (x,0,0,0)$}

Well considering the canonical basis of the polynomials of degree equal or less than 3 we have $(x,0,0,0) = x \times 1 + 0 \times t + 0 \times t^2 + 0 \times t^3 $ which means the eigenspace consists in the constant polynomials.

Comment: What do you mean by *vectors of coordinates of my linear transformation*? What are 'coordinates' of a linear transformation?

Comment: Give a few minutes to edit the question to illustrate with an example what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Done! Can you help me @Servaes

Comment: Thank you for the clear elaboration. Unfortunately I still don't understand what you mean by the phrase *vectors of coordinates of my linear transformation*. I think we have different understandings of the words used. What do you mean by *coordinates* here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not taking my course in English and sometimes I might mistranslate some concepts that usually have another term in english. I mean Coordinate vector: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector

Comment: Then if I understand correctly, are you asking whether eigenvectors are columns of a matricial representation of your linear transformation, for a suitable basis?

Comment: Yes, basically what I want to confirm is that when I calculate the eigenspace of a matricial representation of a linear transformation, for calculating the eigenspace of the transformation itself (in this case I needed to calculate a polynomial) I need to take take my vector and apply it to the basis of the space, right?

Comment: That sounds about right. But what does it mean to apply a vector to a basis?

Comment: Basically it's what I did in my example. Since my ordered basis is $(1,t,t^2,t^3)$ I took the vector I obtained $(x,0,0,0)$ and "applied" it in my basis (basically as a linear combination). $(x,0,0,0)=x\times 1+0 \times t+0 \times t^2+ 0 \times t^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of endomorphisms of $E$  ( $dimE= n$), is isomorphic to
the space of square matrices of order n; but this is not canonical
isomorphism, it depends on the basis of E chosen,  the
expression of  eigenvectors  also depends on the basis. The invariant element which does not
depend on the basis are eingenvalues, eingenspace also the dimension of the
eingenspace. In your example, the eingenspace relatively to the
only eingenvalue is the  constant espace, and  a vectors in this space
 is expressed in the
new basis $ \{v_1 = 1 + t,  v_2=t-1 , V_3 = t ^ 2 , v_4= t ^ 3
\}$ of $E$    by $  a(v_1- v_2) $ for some  $a \in \Bbb{R}$.
Good luck

Comment: Nitpicking: They are called *eigen-*, not *eingen-*. The word is based - also in English - on the German word "eigen" (roughly meaning "own" or "characteristic")

Comment: Thank you, and I hope it gives no confusion this mistyped.